# How to pass date id from one jsp to another jsp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am calculating the price of a ticket with discount on weekdays and weekends based on the time duration.So, i gave inputs of duration and  date using datepicker plugin which is in Above Page. For this i am getting proper result.But i have to create two different jsp pages(date.jsp and cal.jsp).
 In 1st jsp page(date.jsp) i am selecting date using datepicker. And in 2nd jsp page(cal.jsp)

I have written a `method ->[caluculate(#dateid,#duratiionid)]` to calulate the price by taking inputs as time duration.

Here My Question is how shall i pass `[#dateid]` from 1st jsp page(date.jsp) to 2nd jsp page(cal.jsp) 
so that i can pass both the id's in this `method->[caluculate(#dateid,#duratiionid)]`.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="form">
        <form id="book_court">
            <div class="fieldset">
            <fieldset>
                <legend class="visuallyhidden">Booking Details</legend>
                <h2>Booking Details</h2>                 
                <p>
                    <label for="date">Date<br/><span id="dateNote">Firefox does not have a HTML5 datepicker <a href="https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/986096">yet</a>.</span></label>
                    <input type="date" name="date" id="date" min="today" required />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="tickets_duration"> Hours</label>
                    <input type="number" min="1" name="tickets_duration" id="tickets_duration" required />
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label>Total Price</label>
                    <span id="total_price">(enter data first)</span>
                </p>
                <div id="submit_wrapper">
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Book Court" />
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
        </div>
<script id="worker" type="javascript/worker">
    self.onmessage = function msgWorkerHandler(event){
        var jsonString = event.data;

        var day = jsonString.day;
        var tickets_duration = jsonString.tickets_duration;

        // set price of each hours as Rs. 200 and 300
        var totalPriceOnWeekday = tickets_duration * 200;
        var totalPriceOnWeekends=tickets_duration * 300;

        // 10% discount if on weekday and 15% on weekends
        if(day > 0 && day < 6){
            totalPriceOnWeekday = totalPriceOnWeekday - 0.10 * totalPriceOnWeekday;
           postMessage("&#x20b9; " + totalPriceOnWeekday);
        }else if(day == 0 || day == 7){
            totalPriceOnWeekends = totalPriceOnWeekends - 0.15 * totalPriceOnWeekday;

        postMessage("&#x20b9; " + totalPriceOnWeekends);
      }
    }
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    // first check the movies already book

    // apply jQuery UI Redmond theme to 'Book Tickets' button
    $("#submit").button();

    // calculateTotalPrice on keyup or on change of movie/date/tickets
    $("#date, #tickets_duration").change(calculateTotalPrice);

    // on form submit
    $("#book_court").submit(function(event){

        // prevent on submit page refresh
        event.preventDefault();

        // check locally stored data     
        // clear the form                   
        $( '#book_court' ).each(function(){
            this.reset();
        });

        // reset (enter data first) message
        $("#total_price").html("(enter data first)");

        // update movies booked list
    });

    // set minimum date in datepicker as today
    var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
    document.getElementsByName("date")[0].setAttribute('min', today);

});

function calculateTotalPrice(){
    if($("#tickets_duration").val() != "" && $("#date").val() != ""){
        if(window.Worker){
            // create web worker
            var blob = new Blob(
                [document.querySelector("#worker").textContent],
                {type: 'text/javascript'});
            var worker = new Worker(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));

            worker.onmessage = function(event){
                $("#total_price").html(event.data);
            }
            worker.onerror = function(errorObject){
                $("#total_price").html("Error: " + errorObject.message);
            }               
              var date = new Date($('#date').val());

            // get day
            var day = date.getDay();

            // get number of booked shows

            // send JSON data to worker                     
            var jsonData = {'day': day, 'tickets_duration': Number($("#tickets_duration").val())};
            worker.postMessage(jsonData);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share a value cross-pages, you can use cookie to store the value. Another option is localStorage/sessionStorage if you are using HTML5.
So, in the first page (date.jsp), when user select a date, you can store that selection to cookie, in the second page (cal.jsp) you can read that value from cookie and then do your calculation.

I suppose that you are able to post the date string back to servlet. In the servlet, you are using that date string to check for ticket validity. You just don't know how to check if the date is weekday or weekends. If so you can you the `java.util.Calendar` for that purpose. 
***EDITED***

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date yourDate = formatter.parse(dateInString);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(yourDate);
int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Comment: Thanks# Can you give more details? By giving sample code.

Comment: Is there any server-side code involved in this flow? If so, you can post the selected date to server and then do calculation there and display in cal.jsp. If there is no server-side code, then you can use "document.cookie" to save the selected date in date.jsp, and then use the same "document.cookie" to retrieve it in cal.jsp for calculation.

Comment: yes. i am using servlet and MySQL to storing date.But i dont know how to  calculate price(weekday + weekends) in server side ???...Can you please give me a sample of code..#thanks

Comment: Can you tell me why you have to split  the flow into 2 pages? Does that mean users firstly see the "date.jsp" then they can  select a date and then "submit" to "cal.jsp" for calculation?

Comment: yes. its just like a booking a seat for movie if seat is available. So to check for seat availability i have to select date and time first (date.jsp) then finally i have to display price in 2nd jsp page(cal.jsp)

Comment: I suppose that you are able to post the date string back to servlet. In the servlet, you are using that date string to check for ticket validity. You just don't know how to check if the date is weekday or weekends. If so you can you the Caldendar object as below

Comment: here i am taking date as String type to display date in IST  format(dd//mm/yyyy) because in MySQL date format is yyyy/mm/dd..But according to you if i use setTime then date must be Date datatype..Now how can i fix this.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the Date formatting part.